# Adding +1 to specific matrix elements

Tags: python, matrix, vector, addition

I'm currently coding an algorithm for 4-parametric RAINFLOW method. The idea of this method is to eliminate load cycles from a cycle history, which is normally given in a load (for example force) - time diagram. This is a very frequently used method in mechanical engineering to determine the life span of a product/element, that is exposed to a certain number of the load cycles.

However the result of this method is a so called FROM-TO table or FROM-TO matrix where the rows present the FROM and the columns present the TO number like shown in the picture below:

[example of from-to table/matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qThUe.png)

This example is non-realistic as you normally get a file with million points of measurements which means, that some cycles won't occur only once(1) or twice (2) like its shown in the table, but they may occur thousands of times.

**Now to the problem:**
I coded the algorithm of the method and as a result formed a vector with FROM values and a vector with TO values, like this:

```
vek_from=[]
vek_to=[]
d=len(a)/2

for i in range(int(d)):
    vek_from.append(a[2*i]) #  FROM
    vek_to.append(a[2*i+1]) #  TO
```

a is the vector with all values, like a=[from, to, from, to,...]

Now I'm trying to form a matrix out of this, like this:

```
mat_from_to = np.zeros(shape=(int(d),int(d)))
    MAT = np.zeros(shape=(int(d),int(d)))
    s=int(d-1)
    for i in range(s):
        mat_from_to[vek_from[i]-2, vek_to[i]-2] += 1
```

So the problem is that I don't know how to code that when a load cycles occurs several times (it has the same from-to values), how to add +1 to the FROM-TO combination every time that happens, because with what I've coded, it only replaces the previous value with 1, so I can never exceed 1...

So to make explanation shorter, how to code that whenever a combination of FROM-TO values is made that determined the position of an element in the matrix, to add a +1 there...

Hopefully I didn't make it too complicated and someone will be happy to help me with this.

Regards,

Luka